# How do I get the rolling proportion between multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

For every row, I want to have a proportion of the total values (sales). For instance, for some row, we would take the total of the 2 past values of two columns, and compute the proportion of each column.

Let's say we have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'factory1sales': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'factory2sales': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
})
```

```
   factory1sales  factory2sales  rolling_proportion_factory1  rolling_proportion_factory1
0              0              5      
1              1              6      
2              2              7      
3              3              8      
4              4              9  0.25                         0.75
```

The rolling proportion of sales for `factory1` would be (with a window of 2):

```
(2 + 3) / ((2 + 3) + (7 + 8)) = 0.25
```

How can I achieve this? I know it's probably going to be a combination of `pd.shift`, `pd.rolling`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) + [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html), then compute `rolling_proportion_factory2` from `rolling_proportion_factory1` since both sum to 1:

```
df['rolling_proportion_factory1'] = (df.rolling(2, closed='left').sum()
                                       .eval('factory1sales/(factory1sales+factory2sales)')
                                    )
df['rolling_proportion_factory2'] = 1-df['rolling_proportion_factory1']
```

Output:

```
   factory1sales  factory2sales  rolling_proportion_factory1  rolling_proportion_factory2
0              0              5                          NaN                          NaN
1              1              6                          NaN                          NaN
2              2              7                     0.083333                     0.916667
3              3              8                     0.187500                     0.812500
4              4              9                     0.250000                     0.750000
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also able to make it work with chained `shift`, `rolling`, `sum`, etc. Ideally, it could be simplified to be read more easily.

```
for column in columns:
    sum_one_factory = df.shift(1).rolling(2)[column].sum().values.ravel()
    sum_all_factories = df.shift(1).rolling(2)[columns].sum().sum(axis=1)

    df[f'rolling_proportion_{column}'] = sum_one_factory / sum_all_factories
```

```
rolling_proportion_factory1sales  rolling_proportion_factory2sales
NaN                               NaN
NaN                               NaN
0.083333                          0.916667
0.187500                          0.812500
0.250000                          0.750000
```